# how to write regex in php with abba pattern like?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to write down the regular expression in PHP where match the pattern like `baab` but it should not match `aaaa` in the string. Can you please help? My code is as follow:

```
$regex = '/(\w)(\w)\2\1/';
```

But in the above regex, they match both the pattern `baab` as well as `aaaa`, but I need only `baab` not `aaaa`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the second `\w` match a word char other than the one matched with the first `\w`, you may use

```php
$regex = '/(\w)(?!\1)(\w)\2\1/';
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OEI2ZN/1).

*Details*:

- `(\w)` - Capturing group 1: any word char
- `(?!\1)` - the next char cannot be the same as the one captured into Group 1
- `(\w)` - Capturing group 2: any word char (but the one preceeding it)
- `\2\1` - Group 2 value and then Group 1 value.

Comment: Hi Wiktor,

I need php regex solution for skipping the following line-

atta[rttr]ggfdfg

As you can see above, here is a pattern "atta" present in outside the square brackets and the pattern "rttr" present within the square brackets, so it should be skip or return false.

Now look the following another line-

atta[rtyrt]ggfdfg

Here the pattern "atta" outside the square brackets but the similar like pattern not present within the square brackets, so it shouldn't skip the line or return true. Can you please help?

Comment: @PiushGupta No idea what you actually mean, but [this works](https://regex101.com/r/OEI2ZN/2).

Comment: This works but if the string is atta[sdfrttrasas]ffdg or atta[rttrsfsdf]sdf or attasff[sfsdfdrttr]asdsdf. This should also not return because the pattern "rttr" present within the square bracket.

Comment: @PiushGupta This is far from being efficient, but [this works](https://regex101.com/r/OEI2ZN/3).

Comment: This will work. Thanks. In the last string i.e. "atta[rtyrt]ggfdfg" in https://regex101.com/r/OEI2ZN/3 it will return true and this is fine but when I enter "atta[rtyrt]ggfdfgassa" i.e. "assa" at the end, it matched whole string, I need only the exact pattern

Comment: This is the point where it becomes too unclear what output you want. "Exact pattern" usually means "the whole string".